# Kendo chart category able and series position customization

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo chart for our project and i have some specific requirement to customize my category labels like under line as well as position the series to left and right as shown in attached images.
Could and body let me know how to achieve the desired layout.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What does your data look like? What have you tried so far? You can use the visual property to format labels and stacked bar to get the horizontal look.

Comment: its not about data and also I don't want to use visual property, is there any way to adjust the series bar top, bottom in between majorGridLines.
As i said i don't want to use visual properties because we have to customize both labels and series